# Better way to update html page content with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to update html page content with chrome extension. How to do it?

Is it possible to do with chrome.webRequest? I can't found example.

Or I can do it only by javascript when page will be loaded and ready?

manifest.json

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["process.js"]
    }
  ]
```

process.js

```
var html = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
html = html.replace("change this","to this");
document.documentElement.innerHTML = html;
```

Better way for me show already fixed page.

Comment: There are various ways, but a contnt script is the best option imo. Replacing the whole `innerHTML` of the documentElement is generally **not** a good practice, but I need more details in order to suggest a better approach (i.e. what exactly are you trying to achieve).

Comment: I need to translate some buttons on page and add one new.

Comment: OK, then just use the content script to manipulate the DOM (e.g. `document.getElementById(...).appendChild(...)` etc).